# Telegram PHP oauth2 not working as expected (Symfony 5.4)

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I am building Symfony 5.4 app. I want to let my users log in / sign up with telegram api.

However I do not want to use the default widget. I want to build the flow with a controller and a authenticator classes.

The problem I am facing is that when I redirect them to the telegram auth page and they agree to sign in with telegram the callback is never returned from telegram api and the window just closes so I cannot authenticate the user.

I use *knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle* and I created a custom provider for telegram.

This is my custom provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Client;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class TelegramAuthProvider extends AbstractProvider
{

    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return 'https://oauth.telegram.org/auth';
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return 'https://oauth.telegram.org/auth';
    }

    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
        return 'https://oauth.telegram.org/auth'. $token;
    }

    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return ['user_info'];
    }

    protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        if (empty($data['error'])) {
            return;
        }
    }

    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

This is my TelegramController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class TelegramController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Link to this controller to start the "connect" process
     *
     * @Route("/connect/telegram", name="connect_telegram_start", options={"expose" : true})
     */
    public function connectAction(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, HttpClientInterface $client)
    {

        return $clientRegistry
            ->getClient('telegram')
            ->redirect([],[
                'bot_id' => $this->getParameter('telegram_bot_id'),
                'origin' => 'https://bet777.io',
                'embed' => '1',
                'return_to' => 'https://bet777.io/register',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/connect/telegram/check", name="connect_telegram_check")
     */
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
    }
}
```

This is my TelegramAuthenticator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;

// your user entity
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GoogleUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;
use Symfony\Component\String\ByteString;

class TelegramAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator implements AuthenticationEntrypointInterface
{
    private ClientRegistry $clientRegistry;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private RouterInterface $router;
    private UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        // continue ONLY if the current ROUTE matches the check ROUTE
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_telegram_check';
    }


    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $query = $request->query;
        $telegramId = $request->query->get('id');

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($telegramId, function () use ($telegramId, $query)
            {

                $userByTelegramId = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['telegramId' => $telegramId]);
                if ($userByTelegramId) return $userByTelegramId;


                $user = new User();
                $user->setTelegramId($telegramId);
                $user->setFirstName($query->get('first_name'));
                $user->setLastName($query->get('last_name'));
                $user->setUsername($query->get('username'));

                $randomString = ByteString::fromRandom(32)->toString();
                $password = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $randomString);

                $user->setPassword($password);
                $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                $this->entityManager->flush();

                return $user;

            })
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {

        $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('homepage');

        return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);

    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/login', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }


}
```

And this is my knp config file:

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        # configure your clients as described here: https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#configuration
        facebook_main:
            # this will be one of the supported types
            type: facebook
            client_id: '%env(OAUTH_FACEBOOK_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(FACEBOOK_SECRET)%'
            # the route that you're redirected to after
            # see the controller example below
            redirect_route: connect_facebook_check
            redirect_params: {}
            graph_api_version: v2.12
        google:
            # this will be one of the supported types
            type: google
            client_id: '%env(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(GOOGLE_SECRET)%'
            # the route that you're redirected to after
            # see the controller example below
            redirect_route: connect_google_check
            access_type: 'offline'
            redirect_params: {}
        telegram:
            type: generic
            provider_class: App\Client\TelegramAuthProvider
            client_id: null
            client_secret: '%env(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)%'
            redirect_route: connect_telegram_check
            redirect_params: {}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this wont work?
Any other suggestions how to implement this flow?

I tried manually providing the same URL for authentication as the widget but same thing happens.

Comment: _"and the window just closes"_ - can you clarify that part, please? I don't see you using popups anywhere, you are just redirecting to the auth URL in an already existing window (or tab) - are you saying that one actually _closes_ now ...?